State-Space Equation of 2 Capacitor and Resistor
Good Day Everyone,
I'm trying to solve for the state-space model of the circuit shown below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Below are my state Variables:
X1=Vc1 ; X2=Vc2
Now, solving for the state variable equations:
I can't seem to separate X1^ and X2^ from each other.
Performing KVL
Vs-X1-X2=0
Using Nodal:
Ic1-Ic2=IR
C1X1^ - C2X2^ = Vc2/R
combining the two equations does not seem to help.
Is there anyone that can shed light on this?
Best Regards,

There are not separate state space variables when one of them is determined by the other one. So that's why you are having difficulties. They aren't free to vary independently since their sum must be the source voltage.

If you still want to do it then you could add a resistor in series with a capacitor, calculating everything you want and finally take the limit of that resistor to zero.
